# Nginx as reverse proxy to Apache with only dynamic content?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

It seems to be universally considered good practise to run Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Apache for serving PHP.

Is this still the case when using a CDN to serve all static assets (images/css/js)?

Obviously serving static files fast is one of the main advantages of having Nginx in front but is it still worth running it with only dynamic requests for it's advantage as a buffer for slow clients?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

In case your project/scripts do not strictly depend on specific or third-party Apache modules it worth to try Nginx/PHP-FPM/APC cache/Memcached bundle to serve dynamic content. It definitely decrease memory usage footprint and allows to handle more requests ceteris paribus.

For high number of popular CMS you can easily find Nginx configuration examples, first place to check is official Nginx site [Configuration section](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration).

Further one can consider usage of `fastcgi_cache` directives from native [HttpFcgiModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule).